How to work with Angular Query adapter from Tanstack tests
I am working with Angular Query with Angular v19 and signals. I was able to implement good solution to work with QueryOptions and injectQuery in the app. How ever it's quite challenging to work with tests with this.
I don't see any example or resource or anything the Internet to have some sort of reference. I had to quit using this library because of this went back to old way declaring services. Anything related to this guide me through it!
Thanks

I mocked the import from @tanstack/angular-query-experimental to return the desired data, like this:
// my-component.ts

export class MyComponent {
  readonly query = injectQuery(() => ({
    queryKey: ['key'],
    queryFn: () => {
      return lastValueFrom(myService.getData())
    }
  }))

  readonly isValid = computed(() => this.query.data().isValid)
}


// my-component.spec.ts

// From the beginning of the spec file

const mockData = {
  id: '1',
  name: 'Abc',
  isValid: true
}

jest.mock('@tanstack/angular-query-experimental', () => ({
  injectQuery: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    data: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(null)
  })),
}));

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  // Something...

  it('should has correct isValid signal', () => {
    jest.spyOn(component.query, 'data').mockReturnValue(mockData);
    expect(component.isValid()).toBe(true);
  })
})


Hope this answer can help you!
